# How can I put HTML tags in a PHP variable?

Tags: php, html, variables

I am trying to make a variable which contains some HTML tags, this isn't working like I want it to. I was hoping someone could tell what I am doing wrong here.

My Code:

```
$foto = "put picture here";
$naam = 'Sieraad1';
$prijs = '20,00';

$artikel = '<img src="'$foto'"><h4>'$naam'</h4><h6>€'$prijs'</h6>';

echo '<table><tr><td>'.htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($artikel)).'</td><td>'.htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($artikel)).'</td><td>'.htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($artikel)).'</td><td>'.htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($artikel)).'</td></tr>';
echo '<table><tr><td>'.htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($artikel)).'</td><td>'.htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($artikel)).'</td><td>'.htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($artikel)).'</td><td>'.htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($artikel)).'</td></tr>';
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: By the way, <h*> tags go from 1 to 6.

Comment: Why are you calling `htmlspecialchars()` and `stripslashes()` on a variable that doesn't contain user input?

Comment: Eventually it is meant to get the first three values from a database, I am just getting used to PHP so I thought it would be smart to first set up the lay-out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `htmlspecialchars` on html code will convert `<` to `&lt;`, `>` to `&gt;` and `"` to `&quot;`. So it will obviously break your code. Run the `htmlspecialchars` on the inner contents instead:

```
$artikel = '<img src="' . htmlspecialchars($foto) . '"><h4>' . htmlspecialchars($naam) . '</h4><h8>€' . htmlspecialchars($prijs) . '</h8>';
echo '<table><tr><td>'.$artikel.'</td>...';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$artikel = '<img src="'$foto'"><h4>'$naam'</h4><h8>€'$prijs'</h8>';
```

You are missing `.` here between the variables for concatenation.

Comment: That helped a lot! However, it still echo <h1>blabla</h1> instead of blabla in bigger text.. Do you also know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$artikel = "<img src=\"'$foto'\"><h4>'$naam'</h4><h8>€'$prijs'</h8>";
```

or

```
$artikel = '<img src="' . $foto . '"><h4>' . $naam . '</h4><h8>€' . $prijs .'</h8>';
```

then just echo the $artikel - you don't need the htmlspecialchars

Answer (score 0):

var concatenation is missing for variable $artikel. replace user code line with below:

```
$artikel = '<img src="'.$foto.'"><h4>'.$naam.'</h4><h8>€'.$prijs.'</h8>';
```

Answer (score 0):

easy to use

```
<?php
echo <<< END
<table class="head"><tr>
  <td class='head'>$name</td>
  <td>$fname</td>
 </tr></table>
END;
?>
```

or

```
<?php
echo "<table class='head'><tr>
  <td class='head2'>$name</td>
  <td class='head3'>$fname</td>
 </tr></table>";
?>
```